# Using a list to subset a large dataframe

Tags: r, list, subset

I have a large dataframe that I want to subset using a list of factors but don't know how.

This is my dataframe;

```
I_have <- data.frame(
  Company_id = as.factor(c(1006,1007,1123,1556,2000,2006,1200,1277,1266)),
  Value = c(5,6,3,7,9,11,12,17,16))
```

and this is the list of companies I wish to subset by;

```
Companies_needed <- data.frame(Company_id = as.factor(c(1123,1556,2000, 1200)))
```

and this is what I want;

```
I_want <- data.frame(
  Company_id = as.factor(c(1123,1556,2000,1200)),
  Value = c(3,7,9,12))
```

My real data has 500,000 rows in the *"I_have"* dataframe and *"Companies_needed"* has 7,000 rows, so can't type all the combinations so must use the dataframes as lists to subset with.

Comment: Use `%in%` to create a logical vector for subsetting `subset(I_have, Company_id %in% Companies_needed$Company_id)` or join or `merge` methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above use `%in%`

```
I_have[I_have$Company_id %in% Companies_needed$Company_id,]
```

Or with dplyr

```
dplyr::inner_join(I_have, Companies_needed, by = "Company_id")
```